# lspci: what do Revision Number and PCI Class mean?

Tags: linux, laptop, graphics-card

I have a notebook Lenovo IdeaPad G500A (59-381065). OS: openSUSE 13.1. My video cards are  Intel HD Graphics 4000 and AMD Radeon HD 8750M;

```
#  lspci | grep 'VGA\|ATI'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M]
```

My friend has similar notebook (under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) with the same dedicated card, but result of this command contains the revision number (rev ff) for it:

```
# lspci | grep 'VGA\|ATI' 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M] (rev ff)
```

In [forums.amd.com/Support of HD 8750M and linux drivers 14.501.1003 or beta](http://forums.amd.com/game/messageview.cfm?catid=488&threadid=184009&enterthread=y) user has the same AMD card in the HP machine, but it is detected as VGA-compatible device:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M] (rev ff)
```

Could somebody explain

1. what is revision number and what do its particular values and its absence mean?
2. what difference between "VGA compatible" and "display" controllers and why the same card has different PCI classes in different machines?

Or could somebody please give a link, where I can read about this?

---

P.S.

Actually, this issue has arisen from attempts to run the dedicated card with proprietary driver. The final target of this is OpenCL programming.

On the first two listed machines we haven't achieve any success. All versions of AMD driver which support 8750M card were tried with different versions of Intel driver. Various distributions of Linux of various versions were tried too.

In all cases driver is installed, but after reboot X don't start with error

```
(EE) fglrx(0): Failed to open CMMQS connection.
```

The discussion of this general issue can be found in [forums.amd.com/Intel HD 4000 + AMD Radeon HD 8750M + Linux](http://forums.amd.com/game/messageview.cfm?catid=488&threadid=176217&enterthread=y).

Further experiments require deeper understanding, how does it work.

So, thank you in advance for any help.

Regards, Natalia

---

Seems, I have found the revision number of my discrete GPU in /var/log/Xorg.0.log:

```
[    23.516] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0166:17aa:3800 rev 9, Mem @ 0xd8000000/4194304, 0xc0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00004000/64
[    23.516] (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 1002:6600:17aa:3800 rev 0, Mem @ 0xd0000000/134217728, 0xd8600000/262144, I/O @ 0x00003000/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
```

so, it equals 0. But what does it mean?.. What difference between (rev 9) and (rev 0), for example? And this doesn't solve above mentioned issues...

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but it [says here](http://lists.xen.org/archives/html/xen-users/2010-09/msg00315.html) that `rev ff` might mean a bogus revision number caused by bogus PCI data.

Comment: @Vinayak Thank you for the reply and link. Excuse me please for a long absence of response. In [this](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/134) (rev ff) is also mentioned, and it is said, that this value of rev corresponds to switched off device. On the other hand, [here](http://www.linuxspace.org/archives/5537) (some manual, how to install nVidia driver and Steam on Dell XPS 15 laptop under Ubuntu) such value of revision number doesn't hinder to install driver in Intel/nVidia machine...

Comment: I don't have much experience with Linux systems so I can't answer your questions but I did find out about these two bug reports: [segfault after fglrx-installer upgrade](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1275933) and [segfault at Xorg](http://ati.cchtml.com/show_bug.cgi?id=831). I think they may be related to the problem you're facing. It also looks like [8XXX series cards are also affected](http://ati.cchtml.com/show_bug.cgi?id=831#c22) by the bug

Comment: Maybe you could [try disabling switchable graphics in the BIOS](http://www.gentoo-wiki.info/Realtek_RTL8168#Multiple_Cards_.28rev_ff.29) and see if that helps. If nothing works, you could [switch to open source drivers with limited OpenCL support](http://ati.cchtml.com/show_bug.cgi?id=831#c8). These two links might be of interest: [HybridGraphics](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics) and [Blacklist/deactivate 1 graphics card](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=263886).

Comment: @Vinayak Excuse me for a long absence of response. Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately, my integrated card cannot be switched off in BIOS. Once I have tried OpenCL with radeon driver, but Gallium OpenCL SDK hasn't support my GPU yet... About ATI's Bugzilla, I have added a comment to [Bug 1019 - Failed to start X ][1], but I'm not sure that AMD will react on these bugs...

[1]: http://ati.cchtml.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1019/